# stream creates an additional list - how to avoid

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm having a problem figuring out the right way to stream and collect my data.

The stream is the following

```
  public List<List<CalculatedItemCostPerStore>> getCalcualtedItemCostPerStore() {
    var it = item
        .getQuantities().stream().map(quantities -> {
          Store.StoreCosts<CostType, BigDecimal> storeCosts = quantities.getStore().getStoreCosts();
          return new CalculatedItemCostPerStore(quantities.getStore().getName(), new TreeSet<>(quantities
              .getItemCostEvents()
              .stream()
              .map(e -> new CalculatedItemCost(e.getCostTrigger(), e.getTriggerQuantity().multiply(storeCosts.get(e.getCostTrigger()))))
              .collect(
                  Collectors.toMap(CalculatedItemCost::getCostType, Function.identity(), (a, b) -> new CalculatedItemCost(a.getCostType(), a.getCost().add(b.getCost())))
              ).values()));
        }).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CalculatedItemCostPerStore::getStore)).values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    return it;
  }
```

Get's streamed into

```
  @Data
  @AllArgsConstructor
  static class CalculatedItemCost implements Comparable<CalculatedItemCost> {
    private CostType costType;
    private BigDecimal cost;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CalculatedItemCost o) {
      return this.costType.toString().compareTo(o.getCostType().toString());
    }
  }

  @Data
  @AllArgsConstructor
  static class CalculatedItemCostPerStore {
    private String store;
    private TreeSet<CalculatedItemCost> calculatedItemCosts;
  }
```

and itemCostEvents are a list of

```
{
  "createdAt": "2018-08-29T00:00:00",
  "costTrigger": "STORAGE_COST_PER_CBM_PER_DAY",
  "triggerQuantity": 33
}
```

above stream creates a result that is represented by below json. As you can see it's an `List<List<CalculatedItemCostPerStore>>`

```
"calcualtedItemCostPerStore": [
    [
      {
        "store": "foo",
        "calculatedItemCosts": [
          {
            "costType": "ADDITIONAL_COST_OFFICE_PER_HOUR",
            "cost": 1368
          },
          {
            "costType": "STORAGE_COST_PER_CBM_PER_DAY",
            "cost": 287.1
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "store": "bar",
        "calculatedItemCosts": [
          {
            "costType": "ADDITIONAL_COST_OFFICE_PER_HOUR",
            "cost": 38
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
```

There can be any number of occurrences of quantities, of which each can have one store.

What I would like to get is a single `List<CalculatedItemCostPerShop>` like shown below

```
"calcualtedItemCostPerStore": [
    {
        "store": "foo",
        "calculatedItemCosts": [
            {
                "costType": "ADDITIONAL_COST_OFFICE_PER_HOUR",
                "cost": 1368
            },
            {
                "costType": "STORAGE_COST_PER_CBM_PER_DAY",
                "cost": 287.1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "store": "bar",
        "calculatedItemCosts": [
            {
                "costType": "ADDITIONAL_COST_OFFICE_PER_HOUR",
                "cost": 38
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
```

How would I need to adapt my stream to get above result?

Comment: Why not group by `store` and compute a `Map<String, List<CalculatedItemCostPerStore>>` instead of a list of maps?

Comment: The code actually does this, omitting the `.values()` @ernest_k. It's easier for the frontend part to just loop over the single list

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Maybe what you need is to flatten the inner value collections: `.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @ernest_k It worked by using your recommendation, but on the outer list, replacing the last line with `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CalculatedItemCostPerStore::getStore)).values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Looks like what I meant... Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to post it as an answer? @ernest_k

Comment: I'm missing most of the types, so I can't check data types of results. Hope you don't mind posting your verified solution...?

Comment: No problem, just wanted to let you if you like.. @ernest_k

Comment: You could also write your own class collecting the data you need and then stream it into an `Collector.of(YourClass::new, YourClass::accumulate, YourClass::combine, YourClass:createEndResult)`. cfg http://www.deadcoderising.com/2017-03-07-java-8-creating-a-custom-collector-for-your-stream/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it thanks to @ernest_k - using `flatMap` on the `.values()`

```
public List<CalculatedItemCostPerStore> getCalcualtedItemCostPerStore() {
    return item
        .getQuantities().stream().map(quantities -> {
          Store.StoreCosts<CostType, BigDecimal> storeCosts = quantities.getStore().getStoreCosts();
          return new CalculatedItemCostPerStore(quantities.getStore().getName(), new TreeSet<>(quantities
              .getItemCostEvents()
              .stream()
              .map(e -> new CalculatedItemCost(e.getCostTrigger(), e.getTriggerQuantity().multiply(storeCosts.get(e.getCostTrigger()))))
              .collect(
                  Collectors.toMap(CalculatedItemCost::getCostType, Function.identity(), (a, b) -> new CalculatedItemCost(a.getCostType(), a.getCost().add(b.getCost())))
              ).values()));
        })
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CalculatedItemCostPerStore::getStore))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())
        ;
  }
```

Comment: This is insane :D

Comment: your code block has low readability and it makes it hard for reusing it in the future. can you make it more readable so it would have a better impact on other developers? here is something you can do: try not to put lots of codes in one line and try to comment on some parts for the better understanding of what you are doing. since you are using lots of functions after each other. thank you :)